# Node.js - SequelizeDatabaseError: column "user_id" does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, sequelize.js

I have a very simple schema but when I try to make a call for a data it returns me the error

`SequelizeDatabaseError: column "user_id" does not exist`

My database consists of three tables only. Below is the schema file for all of them:

Users

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('users', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function (models) {
    User.hasMany(models.survey_instances)
  };
  return User;
};
```

Survey instances

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const SurveyInstances = sequelize.define('survey_instances', {
    userId: {
      field: 'user_id',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    templateId: {
      field: 'template_id',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    fields: DataTypes.JSONB,
  }, {
    underscored: true,
  });
  SurveyInstances.associate = function (models) {
    SurveyInstances.belongsTo(models.survey_templates, { foreignKey: 'templateId' })
    SurveyInstances.belongsTo(models.users, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
  };
  return SurveyInstances;
};
```

Survey Templates

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const SurveyTemplates = sequelize.define('survey_templates', {
    fields: DataTypes.JSONB,
  }, {});
  SurveyTemplates.associate = function (models) {
    SurveyTemplates.hasMany(models.survey_instances)
  };
  return SurveyTemplates;
};
```

My database is populated and I make the call by:

```
http://localhost:3000/templates?id=1
```

The code handling this endpoint in node is:

```
app.get('/templates', authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
  const templates = await db.survey_instances.findByPk(1);
  res.send(templates);
});
```

I'm new to node so maybe the error is obvious but I cant see it. I would really appreciate it if someone helped me out. Thank you!

Comment: You indicated `user_id` as a field in `survey_instances` model. Did you check if it exists in a real table in DB?

Comment: Hi Anatoly thank you for replying. Okay so yes it does exist but its showing up as `userId` instead of `user_id`. I thought adding `underscored: true` when I was defining my models would have handled it but apparently, there's something wrong going on here. Could you have any idea what?

Comment: How did you create DB structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. There is a bug in the new Sequelize updates that don't make the `underscored: true` option work. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10857).

So I am now just using camel case instead of snake case. Everthing's working now.